# How to load a file using AJAX once and use its data multiple times?

Tags: ajax, jquery, xml-parsing

I have this code where I load an XML file through AJAX:

```
$("#list").on("click", "li", function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.xml',
        type: "get",
        context: this,
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("failure");
        }
    });
})
```

The issue is that I have a long list of clickable elements that use this code which is not very efficient. Is there a way to call AJAX function once and then use the data produced for other items on the list?

Comment: just store the data in another var declared before the ajax call...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just save the return value somewhere

```
$("#list").on("click", "li", function (event) {
    var data = $("#list").data('test');
    if (data){
        //use data
    }
    else{
        $.ajax({
            url: 'test.xml',
            type: "get",
            context: this,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#list").data('test', data);
                // use data
                alert("success");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Just a small note: I separate the AJAX call from the click event using the concept in the answer you gave.